# When editing broken line chart data in a Word file, it returns to the data defined in the form

Tags: apache-poi

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Category
>   and values must have the same point count.    at
>   org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData$Series.replaceData(XDDFChartData.java:111)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow yuanheng, it helps if you provide a minimal working example and a bit more of the stacktrace.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You are calling [public void replaceData(XDDFDataSource<?> category, XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends java.lang.Number> values)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.Series.html#replaceData-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource-) but `XDDFDataSource category` and `XDDFNumericalDataSource values` do not match in point count.